# App is not being found on IOS store

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, ios-appstore

I'm attempting to install the app 'Working Copy - Git client' on my iPad (app link : https://apps.apple.com/us/app/working-copy/id896694807#?platform=ipad) here is a screenshot of the app :

[image]

However when I search for the app on the iPad app store it's not being found :

[image]

I've tried setting the filter to "iPad Only" and "iPhone Only" but its still not being found. How to find the app 'Working Copy - Git client' in order to install it on my iPad ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by updating to latest version of IOS on iPad.

Comment: That was my 1st recommendation. Some apps have software limitations. Glad you have resolved this lol.